# Any idea why flaky plugin is not triggered on failed tests decorated with @pytest.mark.flaky(max_runs=...)

Tags: pytest

I have a pytest suite running in this env:

```
Test session starts (platform: linux, Python 3.6.1, pytest 3.3.1, pytest-sugar 0.9.1)
plugins: flaky-3.5.3, dependency-0.3.2, forked-0.2, logger-0.4.0, sugar-0.9.1, xdist-1.24.1
```

I have a parametrized test, decorated with flaky, and it is supposed to be re-run max three times if it fails.

```py
@pytest.mark.flaky(max_runs=3) # re-run this test in case it fails
def test_cucubau(getBauBau_fixture):
    assert cucubau(getBauBau_fixture) == True
```

However, it fails only once, it is not re-run, and my flaky test report is empty.

```
===Flaky Test Report===


===End Flaky Test Report===
```

Based on what I read about flaky plugin, the usage should be trivial.. but I'm not able to see what is wrong with my code.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the [pytest-rerunfailures](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-rerunfailures/) plugin for that to work. Then you should be able to annotate your test with `@pytest.mark.flaky(reruns=3)`.